# What is the best way to get number of nodes per dc that belong to a Cassandra cluster with multiple DC?

Tags: shell, awk, cassandra

This is an extended version of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/718474/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-list-of-nodes-that-belong-to-a-cassandra-cluster?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

For single DC i can use command like described in above link:

```
nodetool status | awk '/^(U|D)(N|L|J|M)/' | wc -l
```

I am not sure how to get an array of counts for multiple dc. 
The node tool output will be as below:

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  xx.xx.xx.xx    446.13 KB    256          ?     968d5d1e-a113-40ce-9521-e392a927ea5e  rack1
DL  xx.xx.xx.xx    446.13 KB    256          ?     fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767  rack1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  xx.xx.xx.xx    446.13 KB  256          ?       6d28d540-2b44-4522-8612-b5f70a3d7d52  rack1
```

Expected output in above case:

```
2 1
```

Note: i don't want to use peers table as some time some invalid entries might give wrong result however nodetool status is more reliable.

Comment: Please provide output of `nodetool status`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
nodetool status \
| awk '/Datacenter/{ if (cnt) printf cnt OFS; cnt=0 }/^[A-Z]{2} /{ cnt++ }END{ print cnt }'
```

The output:

```
2 1
```

---

- `/^[A-Z]{2} /{ cnt++ }` - on encountering line starting with 2 uppercased node name `[A-Z]{2}` - count/accumulate number of nodes with `cnt++`
- `/Datacenter/{ if (cnt) printf cnt OFS; cnt=0 }` - on encountering `Datacenter` section check if there is previous statistics (node name counts), if so - print it `printf cnt OFS` and reset `cnt` variable to separate counting
- `END{ print cnt }` - print last statistics

Comment: pls add some explanation.

Comment: yes it works..it would be great if you add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Laxmikant, ok, see my explanation